# How to apply contour on its corresponding original image in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

with this code, All contour draw on a single image only and I want to draw each contour to its corresponding original image.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    import glob
    import os

    path = 'C:\pfm\segmented\original_cropped/*.jpg'

    for file in glob.glob(path):
        img = cv2.imread(file)

    path2 = 'C:\pfm\segmented/*.jpg'
    folderlen2 = len(path2)
    for file in glob.glob(path2):

        img2 = cv2.imread(file)
        image2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        from scipy import ndimage as nd
        gaussian_img = nd.gaussian_filter(image2, sigma=3)

        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gaussian_img, 127,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 

        for cnt in contours:

            cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0),2)
            plt.imshow(img)
```